# Reddit search api - searching by subbreddit

Tags: xml, json, api, search, reddit

I've been following the [Reddit API documentation](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search) but I think I'm doing something wrong. When I try searching one particular subreddit for a query, it brings back results for *all* subreddits.

In this example I want to return all the posts in /r/Volvo relating to wagons, however the query returns corresponding posts for numerous subbreddits.

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/volvo/search.xml?q=wagon
```

So am I missing something glaringly obvious? (I guess I am!)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior returns results from all subreddits.

To restrict results to the subreddit, multireddit, or domain-listing in the URL, use the `restrict_sr` query parameter, like so:

```
http://www.reddit.com/r/volvo/search.xml?q=wagon&restrict_sr=on
```

See also https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search